# It it correct to say "I let the balloon go and it landed on the ceiling"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

There are 2 types of balloons. One can not fly, if you let it go it will land on the ground. The other one can fly, if you let it go it will fly into the air.

[image]

Look at the picture above, the balloons flew and were stuck on the ceiling.

Is it natural to say "**I let the balloon go and it landed on the ceiling**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *land* is to come down (to the ground!). The balloons have flown/floated *up* to the ceiling

Comment: Or it ended up on the ceiling.